# Draggable containment to four div

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I have 10 elements which should be draggable in four divs ( containment ). If I wrap all the four divs in a wrapper, then the element can be placed in the middle between two divs. I have given the image link https://i.stack.imgur.com/4T83c.png for your reference.

Is it possible to place it within the four div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know did i understood the question, but maybe this code snippet can solve problem

```js
$( function() { 

 // Let the  items be draggable
 $(".draggable").draggable({
   cancel: "a.ui-icon", // clicking an icon won't initiate dragging
   revert: "invalid", // when not dropped, the item will revert back to its initial position
   containment: "document",
   helper: "clone",
   cursor: "move"
 });

 // Let the wrap be droppable, accepting the items
 $(".droppable").droppable({
   accept: ".draggable",
   classes: {
  "ui-droppable-active": "ui-state-highlight"
   },
   drop: function(event, ui) {
  ui.draggable.appendTo(this);
   }
 });

});
```

```css
.wrap_left {
 width: 20%;
 padding: 4%;
 border: 1px solid black;
 height: 700px;
 float: left;
}

.draggable {
 width: 100px;
 height: 50px;
 padding: 5px%;
 border: 1px solid red;
 margin: 10px;
}

.wrap_right {
 width: 60%;
 padding: 4%;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 height: 700px;
 float: right;
}

.droppable  {
 width: 40%;
 margin: 4%;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 height: 40%;
 float: left;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="wrap_left">
 <div class="draggable" id="drag_1">Goal 1</div>
 <div class="draggable" id="drag_2">Goal 2</div>
 <div class="draggable" id="drag_3">Goal 3</div>
 <div class="draggable" id="drag_4">Goal 4</div>
 <div class="draggable" id="drag_5">Goal 5</div>
 <div class="draggable" id="drag_6">Goal 6</div>
 <div class="draggable" id="drag_7">Goal 7</div>
 <div class="draggable" id="drag_8">Goal 8</div>
 <div class="draggable" id="drag_9">Goal 9</div>
 <div class="draggable" id="drag_10">Goal 10</div>
</div>

<div class="wrap_right">
 <div class="droppable" id="wrap_right_1"></div>
 <div class="droppable" id="wrap_right_2"></div>
 <div class="droppable" id="wrap_right_3"></div>
 <div class="droppable" id="wrap_right_4"></div>
</div>
```